# Show $((0,1),\mathcal{U}_{(0,1)})$ and $((0,4),\mathcal{U}_{(0,4)})$ are homeomorphic.

Tags: general-topology

This is what I have:

Need to show that $f:(0,1) \rightarrow (0,4)$ given by $f(x)=4x$ is a homeomorphism

So I've shown that f is continuous and an open function which is part of the proof, but the part that I'm stuck is how to show that f is bijective. How do you show that a function is one-to-one and onto?

Answer (score 1):

One way is just to write down an explicit inverse function. In this case we have

$$y = 4x \iff x = \frac{y}{4}$$

so consider the function $$g(x) = \frac{x}{4}.$$ Now can you show that $f$ and $g$ are inverses?

Comment: Since (f o g)(x)=f(g(x))=g(f(x))=(g o f)(x) then f and g are inverses